# Can I candy pomegranate?

Tags: fruit, candy, pomegranate

It seems that making candied fruit is easy: cut it thin and boil in sugar syrup until ready.

I'd like to make candied pomegranate, keeping the seed-surrounding bubbles intact. Will it work, or will the membrane prevent the sugar from entering? Can I do something (e.g. stick a pin into a few places) without losing the shape?

Comment: You might want to try getting all of the arils, boil them in the syrup, then lay them out to harden like a brittle.

Comment: @Joe Harden? The point is not to get them hard, but soft

Comment: what would you call the crystalization as final bits moisture evaporates?  I'm not saying to cook it as far as you would a for a brittle, just spread it out so it can cool.

Answer (score 5):

In India, there are typical traditional ways of Candying the Fruits like Pickling, Drying, etc. In your case with Pomegranate, you can always try Combination of Pickling & Drying.

Try the following method,

- Step 1: Make a 1/4 Inch Layer of Powdered Sugar in a Transparent Glass Jar
- Step 2: Follow it with a Layer of Pomegranate (Note: Pomegranate must be spread horizontally & not Stacked Vertically)
- Step 3: Repeat Steps 1 & 2 (Last Layer should always be of Sugar)
- Step 4: Take a Cotton Cloth & tie it on Mouth of Jar, covering Until Neck.
- Step 5: Expose the Jar in Sun for Few Days.
- Step 6: Empty & Spread the Contents of Jar on a Baking Tray & allow it to Dry in Sun for a Day.

Though, the process is not Instant & very Tedious. But this slow cooking process will help to Lock the Freshness, Taste & Essentials in any Fruit in best Man-Made Way.

I Usually do this with Seasonal Fruits.